# Simulink: Vector summation and saving the output to workspace

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, simulink, summarize

I can not solve a very simple problem in the Simulink: **summation of 2 equal size vectors and writing the result into the Matlab workspace**.

The trivial operation that takes 1 line in Matlab seems a real problem in the simulink.

I have 2 vectors with the same size, for e.g. 10x1 and I want to get their summation result into the workspace with the same size (10x1).

I have already used 'sum' block for that and even my own function with element-wise summation, but I think the problem is that Simulink block '*to workspace*' always concatenate outputs either along 1-st or 3-rd dimension. Hence the size of the output does not inherit the size of inputs.

I can not find any solution in the web, will be really appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't notice the vectors are saved in a column-based using "to workspace" block. Did you try to add "(:)" in your code to get it in a single column?

[image: Simulink model example]

As I know, storing the data in columns (1x10) is faster than in rows (10x1). Maybe that is the reason for getting columns instead of rows.
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/216512-which-is-faster-a-row-vector-or-a-column-vector-can-anyone-answer-me-please